# Setting profile information for test user in apex test class

Tags: apex, unit-test

I'm creating a test method where I have to create a test user. I will be using `runAs` for this. But, in creating the actual test user, I'm unsure how to set profile items such as `PermissionsApiUserOnly`. Here is my code so far (taken from documentation):

```
    Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='Standard User']; 
    User u = new User(Alias = 'standt', Email='standarduser@testorg.com', 
        EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', LastName='Testing', LanguageLocaleKey='en_US', 
        LocaleSidKey='en_US', ProfileId = p.Id, 
        TimeZoneSidKey='America/New_York', UserName='standarduser@testorg.com',
        Profile.PermissionsApiUserOnly='true');
```

But, I get

> Invalid field Initializer error on Profile.PermissionsApiUserOnly

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually find a `Profile` that has that permission enabled. **You cannot modify `Profile` permissions in your tests.**

One alternative solution if you do not have any `Profile` set up with that permission (or simply wish to use another) is to create a `Permission Set`. Then you could create a `PermissionSetAssignment` for the `User` in question.

```
PermissionSet p = [SELECT Id FROM PermissionSet WHERE DeveloperName = 'API_Only'];
insert new PermissionSetAssignment(AssigneeId=u.Id, PermissionSetId = p.id);
```

Comment: Also, there is no need to put quotes around `true`, since it is not a string, but a boolean.

Comment: @SebastianKessel Good eye. I didn't even notice b/c I was wrapped up in the strategy itself.

Comment: Looks like DeveloperName for PermissionSet is out of date now - you can use 'Name' instead.